# Why are integers not converting to ASCII in C?

Tags: c, casting, char, int, ascii

I have a snippet of code that goes through the first 256 characters of what I thought was ASCII, outputs the character, and outputs the occurrences of that string in a text file. What is curious is that the characters it outputs doesn't correspond to any ASCII table online. The first character (i = 0) is empty, but the second and third characters are smiley faces followed by a heart, diamond, club, and spade. What is even more curious is that when I check the alphabet ((char)65 = 'A', ...), everything works fine and corresponds to ASCII. Why is this? It only messes up before and after the more standard symbols, saying (char)254 = an integral sign. This is definitely not ASCII...

If it is any consolation, I am running this program through Code::Blocks on a windoes 8 machine.

My code:

```
void display ()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<256; i++)
   {
       printf("Character: %c", (char)i);
       printf("\tOccurrences: %d", characterCount[i]);
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: You can only output the *printable* ASCII characters (which start at decimal 32, or `0x20` hex). Values below that have no representation, which is why you get the strange symbols.

Comment: no related,  `(char)` is not required. `%c` of printf will request the `int`.

Comment: Google "ASCII table".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY More accurately, [the varargs promotes char and short int to int, and float to double](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html).  The "%c" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You can have multiple conversion specifications in a single `printf()`, so you could (perhaps should) write: `printf("Character: %c\tOccurrences: %d\n", i, characterCount[i]);`

Comment: @HostileFork i know promotes char. "`c` If no l length modifier is present, the **int argument** is converted to an
unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."

Comment: @HostileFork What you say even with the same result is the reverse.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm not clear on what you are saying.  Your original comment was advising that the char cast was not necessary, with which I agree.  But you said *"(char) is not required. %c of printf will request the int"*.  I was just pointing out that the reason the cast is meaningless comes from the behavior of varargs; not from anything about how the format specifiers work.  Because printf *can't* get a char parameter.  So I was just wanting to be a bit more specific on why the cast makes no difference.

Comment: @HostileFork "Cast by `(char)` is not necessary because char type since promoted to int" yes, i agree. But just because I can not agree with The "%c" has nothing to do with it. It is because the Type as an argument to request is not a type promotion reason to determine the type of the argument.

Comment: @HostileFork To put it plainly, the request of the function determines the type of the argument.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I still don't quite understand what you're saying.  I believed the point you were making was about why the cast was unnecessary.  I believe that is solely a property of the inability of varargs to pass a char to printf.  So whatever the rest of it you are talking about is something else, about what printf does with the int afterwards that it gets.  I don't see that as relevant to whether you put a cast or not.

Comment: @HostileFork I give up that you to understand it.

Comment: perhaps the loop should only output characters that were found in the input data.  perhaps use the functions to check for alpha and for numeric and if passing, then print the char otherwise print using a format of "02x%"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCII designates all of the characters from the initial 32 of 128 as non-printable. Some encodings which are  based on ASCII assign graphical representations to these characters. They also assign graphical representations to characters 128 and above, which are not even part of ASCII encoding. For example, a common PC encoding called [Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) assigns smiley faces to characters 1 and 2, characters depicting card suits to characters 3 through 7, and so on.

What you described looks very much like Page 437. However, this behavior is very much system-dependent.

Comment: Actually, all of the initial 32 are non-printable control characters.  "page 437" is not ASCII.